# codeigniter join many to many LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, group-concat

I have three tables:

```
products: model_id, model(unique),
groups: group_id, code(unique), 
products_groups: pg_id, model_id_fk, group_id_fk
```

products_groups table is for 'many-to-many' relationship between tables 'products' and 'groups'.

My left join:

```
$this->db->select('model_id, model, code');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('products_group', 'products_group.model_id_fk = products.model_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('groups', 'groups.group_id = products_groups.group_id_fk', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Result:

```
|-------------------------|
| model_id | model | code |
|-------------------------| 
| 0        | 1000  | 15   | 
| 0        | 1000  | 20   | 
| 0        | 1000  | 30   | 
| 1        | 2000  | 15   | 
| 1        | 2000  | 20   |
|-------------------------|
```

What I want:

```
|-------------------------------|
| model_id | model | code       |
|-------------------------------|
| 0        | 1000  | 15,20,30   |
| 1        | 2000  | 15,20      |
|-------------------------------|
```

Solution(?):
The first thing that came to mind, is to do 'order by products.model_id' and then go through the results row by row, merge rows that have the same 'model_id' and concate their 'code' values.

Problem:
I want to do pagination and if I do a limit on the query, the merging of rows will mess up the number of rows.

So I need suggestions, how do I do this ?

P.S. This is only a part of the info, the 'products' table has one more 'many-to-many' relationship with a second table, 'one-to-many' relationship with a third one. Maybe one more 'many-to-many' relationship will be added.

Comment: Woooops the tables are messed up, I will change it.

Comment: The tables are readable now.

Comment: Did you tried grouping them up by model_id `$this->db->group_by('model_id')`?

Comment: @Rolice and applying `GROUP_CONCAT(code)`

Comment: Yep @Stephan, I just threw a hint. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupby model_id and group_concat by code

Comment: You gave the most complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`groups`.`code`) AS "codes"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I get one row:
model: 1000
code: 15,20,30

I browsed the web but found no solution.